# How to determine which I2C commands to execute to arrive at a desired result?

Tags: i2c, uart, python, adafruit

I have successfully established bidirectional communication between a [featherS2](https://feathers2.io/) board and a [Mikroe UART to I2C bridge](https://www.mikroe.com/rs232-to-i2c-click).

I do this by instantiating the address of an I2C command from page 16 of [this datasheet](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/ZDU0110RFX_datasheet.pdf) into a variable, and initializing a `bytearray` object with said variable. It looks like this:

```
readSystemStatusCommand = [0xE1]
inputBuffer = bytearray(readSystemStatusCommand)
outputbuffer = bytearray(64)
i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(0x5b, inputBuffer, outputBuffer)
```

This is returning an `outputBuffer` object with some bytes in it that I can't really decode yet but that's a whole other question. What's important is that it is getting *some* data off of the board.

The problem I'm having is getting any data off of the UART. I plug my Mikroe device into an RS-232 output device and power it up. Then I try to read `RX FIFO` data by loading in the command from the datasheet:

```
readRXCommand = [0x25]
inputBuffer = bytearray(readRXCommand)
outputbuffer = bytearray(64)
i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(0x5b, inputBuffer, outputBuffer)
```

But this returns an array of blank bytes. I've tried to write to the device first to enable UART, in case it needs to be enabled first every time, so before the code above I will use:

```
enableUARTCommand = [0x2E]
inputBuffer = bytearray(enableUARTCommand)
i2c.writeto(0x5b, inputbuffer)
```

That little bit was crashing the code but when I put in a sleep time after:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

It was compiling no problem, however it was still returning a blank array. Unto the crux of my question: **why is this happening? Do I have a fundemental misunderstanding of where the board is keeping/streaming its UART data?** I thought it would be on the `RX`--surely it can't be on `TX` because on this datasheet that is write-only. I have tried reading the EEPROM with a similar chain of commands, but to no avail. It seems the only data I can get related to the UART is the baud rate register. Perhaps there is some chain of commands I need to run to access the UART datastream via I2C?

Comment: What if nothing sends data, so there is no data, and you try forcibly reading 64 bytes out of it? Is the baud rate even correct? Can you read how other people/drivers access the chip over I2C as an example how to make the chip do what you want?

Comment: That's an excellent point, but the originating device is definitely transmitting data--I can see that by connecting it to the computer directly. Great question about the baud rate. Looks like mikroe defaults at 5700, though I don't know what baud rate adafruit i2c prefers...

Even still, if the rates don't match, wouldn't I get corrupted data instead of no data at all? Am I correct in my assumption that the reading RX FIFO command would theoretically be the correct command?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "what baud rate adafruit i2c prefers". You need to set the UART baud rate to match the baud rate your other device is sending. I2C has nothing to do with that.

Comment: You said, "`readSystemStatusCommand`...is returning...some bytes...that I can't really decode yet." Sounds as if you haven't really gotten to know the [data sheet for the UART chip](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/ZDU0110RFX_datasheet.pdf) yet. Command `0xE1` is explained on page 39. You're going to have to write some code to properly configure it to talk to whatever is at the other end of the line (same baud rate, same number of stop bits, same parity, ...)

Comment: @Justme In otherwords, I need to set the baud rate of the mikroe board to match the baud rate the adafruit board is using to establish the serial session with my computer? As far as I know, the adafruit device is ONLY sending I2C signals to the mikroe board, so that's why I thought you were referring to that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've read it--I just don't really understand what I'm reading to be honest. This is my first time operating at such a low level without an off-the-shelf library provided by Arduino or Adafruit or something like that. When you say  "configure it to talk to whatever is on the other end of the line." You mean configure the MIKROE board to communicate to the RS-232 device that's plugged into it, or to the adafruit device it's connected to via i2c?

Comment: @SolomonSlow

Forgive me. I see what you mean now upon reflection. The output device is at 9600 baud, no parity, and 1 or 2 stop bits. I had not even read its data sheet. I thank you. Feel free to leave an answer to that effect and I will mark it solved. You have been most helpful.

Comment: To make your question more helpful, please add a bit more of the code and specifically which library you are using.

Comment: @Z-ManJones You are sending commands to this Mikroe adapter to tell the Mikroe adapter how to talk over UART/RS-232. A bit convoluted. Instead of setting the baud rate directly in your code, like you would if your computer was talking UART, you tell the Mikroe adapter to set the baud rate because it's the Mikroe adapter that is talking UART.

Comment: @user253751 That makes perfect sense. As always the comments are enlightening. At least I now know the correct question to ask

Comment: If this is an embedded Linux system and Linux has a driver for it (not guaranteed) you might be able to customize your device tree file to tell Linux that it's got this UART converter chip. Then Linux would let you access it like any other UART

Comment: @user253751, I don't know, maybe it's just me, but I've always thought that the Unix/Linux approach to serial ports (TTYs, and PTYs, and line disciplines, Oh My!) was more intimidating than just peeking and poking the registers of a UART. OP's problem pretty much _is_ just peeking and poking the registers except he's got to go through I2C to do the peeking and poking.

Comment: @Z-ManJones, I wish I could leave you an answer, but without having the hardware on my desk (and maybe a logic analyzer hooked up to it\*) I don't think I could answer in confidence. That's not a chip that I have ever used.

Comment: * I don't know that I have _ever_ gotten an I2C or SPI device to work without hooking up a logic analyzer. Even a cheap-ass thing like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18627) (I personally own two just like it) can help you to debug serial link and I2C protocols if the voltages are nominal, if the bit rate isn't crazy high, and if you aren't chasing down a signal integrity problem. On the other hand, there's this guy: https://usd.saleae.com/products/saleae-logic-pro-8 It looks sweet on the workbench, but if you ever really _need_ it, then you may be facing a hard-core problem.